# Derive Parseval's theorem in one dimension

Tags: integral-transforms, theorem-proving, fourier-analysis

Parseval's theorem (in one dimension) is a fundamental result in the theory of Fourier transforms.  If $f(t) \Leftrightarrow F(\omega )$ are Fourier transform pairs and $t$ (time) and $\omega$ (angular frequency) are conjugate variables, Parseval's Theorem states (up to a constant of proportionality):

$$\int\limits_{t= - \infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2\ dt = \int\limits_{\omega = -\infty}^\infty |F(\omega )|^2\ d \omega$$

Here both $f(t)$ and $F(\omega )$ can be complex-valued, and $| \cdot |$ denotes the absolute value, and thus $| \cdot |^2$ is real-valued.

It is fairly straightforward to verify Parseval's theorem with the specific case of chosen functions, e.g., $f(t) = e^{-t^2} \cos t$, using `FourierTransform` and `Conjugate`.

My question is instead:  How can one most elegantly and efficiently *derive* the theorem using the symbol-manipulation power of *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 3):

The following is my trial for automating the manual deduction [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/parseval-s-theorem-and-parseval-s-identity-of-fourier-transform#:%7E:text=Statement%20%E2%80%93%20Parseval%27s%20theorem%20states%20that,power%20in%20the%20frequency%20domain.). You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to transform the output to `TraditionalForm` to make it look good.

```
With[{int = Inactive[Integrate]},

 ftformula[f_] := ℱ[f][ω_] :> int[f[t] Exp[I ω t], {t, -∞, ∞}]/Sqrt[2 π];

 moveconj = Conjugate[int[expr_, tlst : {_, -∞, ∞}]] :> int[Conjugate[expr], tlst];

 mergecoef = int[expr_, {t_, b__}] coef_ /; FreeQ[coef, t] :> int[expr coef, {t, b}];

 exchange = int[int[expr_, tlst_], ωlst_] :> int[int[expr, ωlst], tlst];

 extractcoef = int[coef_ expr_, {ω_, b__}] /; FreeQ[coef, ω] :> coef int[expr, {ω, b}];

 ift = int[ℱ[f_][ω] E^(-I t_ ω), {ω, -∞, ∞}] :> Sqrt[2 π] f[t];

 step[1] = int[ℱ[f][ω] Conjugate[ℱ[g][ω]], {ω, -∞, ∞}]]
```

[image]

```
step@2 = step@1 /. ftformula[g]
(* There's a bug in TraditionalForm of Conjugate@Inactive[Integrate][…]. *)
(* To make the conjugate of integral display properly, use Activate. *)
```

[image]

```
step@3 = Simplify[step@2 /. moveconj, {t, ω} ∈ Reals]
```

[image]

```
step@4 = step@3 /. mergecoef
```

[image]

```
step@5 = step@4 /. exchange
```

[image]

```
step@6 = step@5 //. extractcoef
```

[image]

```
step@7 = step@6 /. ift /. extractcoef
```

[image]

So we manage to deduce

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }(\mathcal{F}(g)(\omega ))^* \mathcal{F}(f)(\omega )d\omega =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }g(t)^* f(t)dt$$

where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ denotes Fourier transform of $f$. Identity in the question is a special case of this identity, because

$$|f(t)|^2=f(t) f(t)^*$$

I admit the procedure still heavily depends on manual analysis so it's not quite satisfactory, but at least it illustrates the deduction without ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks ($+1$)...  Let's wait to see if a more elegant solution arrives.